# Redeveloping MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I've got a program written in c++ and have to make some modifications to it. Howerver, I haven't got any solution file or a like, just a bunch of .h, .cpp, .obj, .dpb, .dll, .mdi, .dfm, .res, .tds, .bpl files and an .exe file.
So I can start an application, see what it's doing and what the controls are, but when it comes to adding changes trying do to map behaviour of UI to source code files seems just to tedious.
Is it possible to recreate some kind of solution file or just to simply the process? (I am using VS 2012 and an app was written in 2002).

Comment: So you cannot build it from source? What makes you think you are just missing solution file and not parts of actual codebase?

Comment: That might be the case, I can't be sure about that. In that case I would have to restore functionality myself (it is a physical device model, so info can be found), but i'd like to restore as much as i can with as little effort as possible.

Comment: you can start creating a new Win32 empty project, then add your files to the project, add MFC to the project properties; see if it builds, what are the errors, etc.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Where did you get it from?

Comment: One of my professors "delegeted" improvements to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These file extensions indicate the source is from a Borland IDE.  That .mdi file I think signifies Borland's multiple-document-interface... I'll venture to guess this project would be quite difficult to "recompile" using Visual Studio.  I don't even see a .rc (resource file) in your list.  Rewriting may be the easiest path, depending on the complexity of the application...